# Django test, ignore missing template

Tags: django, templates, testing

I'm working on this Django app where I don't want to make any default templates, because making templates is up to the designer. But I still want to test my views to make sure that they work as expected. But the tests fails because there are no templates, and I dont like the tought of making blank default templates, because that would give the impression that the app would work "stand alone" which it wont.

Is there a good way to make the test ignore missing templates, but stille let you inspect what variables would have been sent to the template? :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your rationale for the not creating completely blank templates? I'm assuming you already explicitly call the template names in the views, so does it hurt to save blank files for your designer? Just a thought.

Comment: @j_syk: If no one elses comes sup with a neat solution to this here, I guess thats what I'll have to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should split up your view into two parts:

```
# test this
def _my_view(request):
    return {'var_one': var_one, 'var_two': var_two}

def my_view(request):
    return direct_to_template(request, _my_view(request))
```

But are you sure you can't place the logic that can cause errors somewhere else (models, forms, some "core.py")?

Answer (score -1):

best answer in the world : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/
:P

Comment: cool, he/you wanted unit testing for its/your application and he/you get the docs where it's explained how to test the application, and the answer is not good? can i just know why?

Comment: It wasnt me who rated down you'r comment, but the answer was no good anyway because the documentation does not answer this question. The issue is not that i dont know how to write unit tests in django, I hade a very specific question about making render_to_response ignore missing templates during testing. Or tips on alternative methods to do testing when no defualt template is included in the app.

Comment: you're not saying you want to test render_to_response without a template, just "test my application without templates". btw https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response the template is a required argument, if you want to test your views just stick with unit testing.

Comment: You're not helping, just being rude. I asked for a way to ignore missing templates while testing VIEWS! And even after reformulating the question you still doesnt seem to have a helpful answer, so why do you keep replying? 

I know the template is a requierd argument, but python is a programming language, you can use if-cases and other funky stuff you know to make exceptions.

Comment: sorry. i gave you the answer you need. you don't like it, i get it. i know you're testing VIEWS. render to response REQUIRES a template, you cannot test it, you have to test your view function/class. best practice says you have to use unit testing. worst practice says you can use prints and check out by yourself. mystical practice says that the template is not required even if its required. good luck with other answers. i'm not being rude, just practical. bb.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo It's my -1. I don't think "RTFM" is good answer. At least you can use comments for that. And the problem really does exist. You can, for example, run tests for [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) without templates. Some of them will fail. You believe it's normal behavior?

Comment: i gave him the best solution to test without fails template-dependent. it's normal behaviour what? my "rtfm" answer or the "test that sometimes fails"? this is not a flame, just to be clear, i want to understand what is really wrong in this post, so i can learn something too. direct_to_template requires a template too. if you want to have strong tests on your logic, you don't need to evaluate with weak tests (like calling render_to_response without a custom/default template and just "hope" the failure is because of logic and not because of template missing)

Comment: @DrTyrsa Had a look at the django-registration app and it's a great example of why I like to achive this! For apps that are made to be an entity of its own, like the contrib.admin app, templates makes perfect sense. But in all other cases it's just alot of extra work, why write code that are not ment to be used? And the tests are there so you dont commit bad code, it's not the designer who's ment to find out that there are variables missing or that the view returns wrong status code.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo Any suggestions how to make this "weak test" "strong" (without violating KISS heavily) would be the great answer.

Comment: i'm still sticking with "testing", i don't think it's KISS-compliant, but you can assume (after a test) that almost everything works.
@sabe: i think i'm not understanding your question completely, atm. if you're the designer then no, you don't have to test anything. if you're the developer, you have to test what variables you pass and their values. that's what unit testing is for: testing methods, testing objects fetched, testing variables, testing exceptions. my suggestion sticks with this...

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzo: Why are you then even trying to answer a question you don't understand? DrTyrsa pointed you to a concrete example with django-registration, if you'd taken 5 minutes to examen the views.py and tests you'd understand the issue. We are'nt idiots who can't read manuals and dont know what unit testing is...

Comment: no one ever said that. i'm not an idiot either. have a nice day and good luck with your problem. i read DrTyrsa link and source code. i still don't like the idea of a test failing because it isn't done as it's supposed to be. i understand the question, i don't understand you, it's different. you don't want to use templates to test a view that uses a template (say, if you use render_to_response or direct_to_template). it's a weak test, it's not even a test, imho. it's just a "try and wish for some lucky output". never said any of you is an idiot.